# Getting WriteTimoutException on CAS operations

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, phantom-dsl

I am trying to insert fairly small amount of data async using [phantom](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom) to `cassandra 3:9` however this query keeps fails :
`INSERT INTO test_db.test_tbl(name, last, ts) VALUES('aaa', 'bbb', 1502109409) IF NOT EXISTS USING TTL 0;` 
I am getting the following exception :

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra
>   timeout during write query at consistency SERIAL (1 replica were
>   required but only 0 acknowledged the write)
>
> at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException.copy(WriteTimeoutException.java:100)
>
> at 
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:134)
>
> at 
>   com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:507)
>
> at com .....

I am running cassandra with docker. I tried to change the cassandra.yaml `write_request_timeout_in_ms: 20000` but that didn't made much difference.

UPDATE: 
I tried setting the consistency level to ONE (also tried other):

```
insert
      .value(_.name, "aaa")
      .value(_.last, uuid)
      .value(_.ts, Random.long)
      .ifNotExists()
      .consistencyLevel_=(ConsistencyLevel.ONE)
```

but the exception still shows "Cassandra timeout during write query at consistency SERIAL"

Answer (score 1):

You are using `IF NOT EXISTS` keyword, which is a [Lightweight transactions](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0)

> Cassandra implements lightweight transactions by extending the Paxos consensus protocol, which is based on a quorum-based algorithm. Paxos make sure linearizable consistency at the cost of four round trips.

**That sounds like a high cost—perhaps too high, if you have the rare case of an application that requires every operation to be linearizable. Consequently, reserve lightweight transactions for those situations where they are absolutely necessary**.

Source : https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0

Comment: actually I am trying to insert just 100-200 records.

Comment: Cost of Lightweight transactions is very high, Try the query without `IF NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score 1):

Same problem,this is my solution:

It only fit a single node.

1. Execute the LWT CQL once,close and init Session  once.
   use com.datastax.driver.core.Session.init().
2. Cluster.Builder.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM)
3. Cluster.Builder.withSocketOptions(newSocketOptions().setConnectTimeoutMillis(300000)
               .setReadTimeoutMillis(300000));

Comment: `setConsistencyLevel` has no effect on the LWTs

Comment: Client need set it,Otherwise you have a timeout problem

Comment: I have a successful demo on my side and will upload it to github later

Comment: Comment was about consistency level... of course setting timeouts may help, but they just hide real problems

Comment: yes, those are just clues, I'm also continuing to find the real cause of the problem.